# Unable to use "IN" with JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get results from a JPA query on a `ManyToMany` relationship. I have to entities -

```
 A.java
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "a_tags")
 private List<Tag> tags;
```

Then I try to Run the following query -

```
Query query2 = entityManager
            .createQuery("select s from A s where s.tags IN(:tags)");
    query2.setParameter("tags", findTags(keyword));
```

But   I keep getting the following error `java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1`.

I have used the `IN` condition before, but only to check for single object in collection.

Any pointers?

Dependency info-

- Hibernate-4.3.5-Final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct s from A s join s.tags t where t IN (:tags)
```

Comment: That worked. Is the `JOIN` required because of the `ManyToMany` mapping? Because IIRC, its not required in a `ManyToOne`.

Comment: True, it is required because tags is a collection (one-to-many or many-to-many).

Answer (score -1):

When using IN with a collection-valued parameter you don't need to use (...)

```
Query query2 = entityManager
            .createQuery("select s from A s where s.tags IN :tags");
    query2.setParameter("tags", findTags(keyword));
```

Comment: query2.setParameterList("tags", findTags(keyword))